# Listing the Document Ready events in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to track down a problem in some very complex Javascript and I need to find all the `jQuery(document).ready(` events that are active on the current screen as one of them is causing the problem.

I just asked a general question about accessing events on jQuery and got a good answer, however unfortunately it's still not solved my specific problem.

I now have:

```
> jQuery._data(document).events
```

Which returns:

```
Object {mouseup: Array[1], touchstart: Array[2], touchmove: Array[1], touchend: Array[1], click: Array[1]…}
   MSPointerOver: Array[1]
   click: Array[1]
   mousemove: Array[1]
   mouseup: Array[1]
   pointerover: Array[1]
   touchend: Array[1]
   touchmove: Array[1]
   touchstart: Array[2]
   __proto__: Object
```

However I'm looking for the list of the **document ready events** as registered using `jQuery(document).ready(` and none of these seem to be that...

Comment: Could you hijack/intercept the ready method and console log calls to it?

Comment: They are probably combined into a single event handler behind the scenes in jQuery. You are better off break-pointing the source code of jQuery in the `ready` method and see where it is called from. Note there are variations on `.ready` like `$(function(){your DOM ready code});` that may go through a slightly different code path.

Answer (score 1):

See this post [readylist-is-no-longer-exposed-in-1-4](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/readylist-is-no-longer-exposed-in-1-4/) . At jquery 1.11.1.js at line 3481 ,

```
readyList = jQuery.Deferred();
```

Though , was able to gather data about `.ready()` `event` function with

```
function evt() {
    $(document)
    .on("click", function(e) {
      alert(1);
    });
    alert(2);
};

    $(document).on("ready", evt);
    console.log(jQuery._data(document
               , "events").ready[0]
               , jQuery._data(document
               , "events").ready[0].handler);
```

where

```
jQuery._data(document, "events").ready[0].handler
```

would be the text of `evt()`

however, if try

```
$(document).on("ready", evt1, evt2);
```

`evt` will be registered as `event.data` , not as type `function`

Could try create object or array of functions , outside of `.ready` or custom `event` , utilize `on` to compile attached functions

add functions to an array , then `dequeue` the array of functions by calling `jQuery._data(document).events` in `$.each()`.

`.ready` appear `jQuery.Deferred()` , could create custom deferred object , called with check of `.isReady` , or called on certain conditions with `$.holdReady(true)` , `$.holdReady(false)` ; or after each function in array of function pass conditions ; return correct `init` type value ?.

Or, not utilize `.ready()` and only utilize custom `.on()` event , or custom deferred resolved with checking conditions of `document` of functions' in array `init`-type values ?

Try

```
function evt() {
    $(document)
    .on("click", function(e) {
      alert(1);
    });
    alert(2);
};

$(document).on("ready", evt);
console.log(jQuery._data(document
           , "events").ready[0]
           , jQuery._data(document
           , "events").ready[0].handler);
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/c4z8pv9p/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I found it a little hard to follow in places it still was very helpful. I'm at home now but I'll be able to try it properly on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you have access to the source, you could overwrite `$.fn.ready`:

```
jQuery.fn.ready = function( fn ) {
    // log the argument
    window.console && console.log(fn);

    // preserve default behaviour
    jQuery.ready.promise().done( fn );

    return this;
};
```

This *does*, of course, need to be included *before* any of the actual `.ready()` calls

example: http://jsfiddle.net/49uksstv/